# How to get data after adding attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, database, query

So, I created adapter:

```
$adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
```

After that I added some attributes for select:

```
$select = $adapter->select();
$select->from(array('o' => $this->getT...
$select->joinLeft(array('address' => $this->getTable('...
$select->joinLeft(array('oh' => ...
```

And now select is object: [image]
How I can submit this query and get response from DB?

Thanks in advance!

I tried:

```
$data = $adapter->query($select);
$data = $adapter->commit();
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the answer in the Magento Core files, you have a lot of examples there.

Try using:

```
$select = $adapter->select()
    ->from(array('o' => $this->getT...
    ->joinLeft(array('address' => $this->getTable('...
    ->joinLeft(array('oh' => ...

$result = $adapter->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: ty. And when I do `$adapter->insert(` I also need to write `$adapter->fetchAll`?

Comment: No. For read operations use fetch, for write operations, commit. Anyway, try to use magento collections and models whenever you can instead of resource connections.